# Java Syntax of SomeClass.class

Tags: java, android, syntax

Recently I have come across the following syntax in Android:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SomeActivityClass.class);
```

Could someone please explain what happens when `SomeActivityClass.class` is called?

Comment: What do you mean by **`SomeActivityClass.class` is called**? If there is an invocation on the `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult` methods with the `i` `Intent` parameter?

Comment: @rekaszeru, I meant when it is invoked, in general.

Comment: please see `@Binyamin Sharet`'s answer, it cannot be `called`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`class` is a static class field of each class, of type `Class<?>` which represents the type of that specific class. It is often used for instantiating a class by [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) (as in the intent case).

i.e. - after:

```
Class<?> clazz = SomeActivityClass.class;
```

`clazz` will refer to an object of type `Class<?>` that represents the `SomeActivityClass` class.

Links:

- [Class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)
- [Using reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) (including class instantiation)

Comment: +1 And note that `Class<SomeActivityClass> clazz = SomeActivityClass.class;` is also possible.

Comment: @Binyamin Sharet, thank you that's very helpful. Would you have a documentation on the Class<?> syntax I could read more about?

Comment: Notice how I managed to use the word **class** 5 times in the first sentence. I have some special talents :-P

Answer (score 1):

When the `Intent` is invoked, it starts the `SomeActivityClass` `Activity` the same as any other `Activity`. ie, calls `onCreate()`, then `onStart()`, etc.

Refer to the flowchart diagram in the `Activity` documentation here...
[image: http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png]

Or see the Activity documentation here... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html